# Showing $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+\lvert{nx}\rvert}$ converges pointwise but not uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I have a sequence of functions defined as $f_n:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+\lvert{nx}\rvert}$

I am supposed to show that this does converge pointwise, but not uniformly. I have never really done this before and am kinda struggling with these exercises. I have seen some graphs from different sequences of functions and intuitively it does make sence. I just struggle computing it correctly.

So I recall having to calculate the pointwise limit function $f$. In other words, showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = f(x), \space \forall x \in \mathbb R$

It seems that I have to check for different cases here. My guess is $\lvert{x}\rvert \lt 0$, $\lvert{x}\rvert = 0$ and $\lvert{x}\rvert >0$

Showing that a sequence of functions converges pointwise, we have to show that $\forall x \in \mathbb R: \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \exists N \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \forall n > N: \lvert{{f_n}(x)-f(x)}\rvert < \varepsilon$.

To calculate $f(x)$, we have to first assume a limit I believe. Since we have three different possible cases, we have to differentiate between them.

So take $x=0$, we get $\frac{n*0}{1+\lvert{n*0}\rvert} = \frac{0}{1} = 0$. Am I making a crucial mistake here already or is this correct and I can proceed from this? I'm not really sure since now $f(x) = 0$ and therefore $\lvert{{f_n}(x)-f(x)}\rvert = \lvert{{f_n}(x)-0}\rvert$ = $\lvert{{f_n}(x)}\rvert$

For  $\lvert{x}\rvert \lt 0$ and  $\lvert{x}\rvert \gt 0$, my guess is that $f(x) = -1$ and $1$. However, again, I'm really unsure about my calculations and it seems that I did not quite understand this enough. Since this is where I'm stuck and do not know how to proceed.

My questions now are: is my work partially correct or did I make some crucial mistakes early on? And also, how can I proceed from this or if it's wrong, how can I solve an exercise like this?

Comment: It never happens that $|x|<0$. You meant "For $x<0$ and $x>0$...". With that corrrection you got$f$ right. Hence the convergence is not uniform, because $f$ is not [...]

Comment: Hint for the part of the calculation where you say you're just guessing: $f_n(x)=\frac x{\frac 1n+|x|}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're right I first wrote it like that but then decided to change it. Thanks! Do i just plug these values into that equation and then solve it? Because that's the step where I'm not really sure